# Is it safe to equal compare DBL_MIN or DBL_MAX?

Tags: c

One of my functions returns a `double` and I'd like to indicate an error condition with an invalid value like for example `DBL_MIN`, `DBL_MAX` or `-DBL_MAX`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

double foo_fail(void)
{
    /* some code that could fail */
    return DBL_MIN;
}

int main(void)
{
    double d = foo_fail();
    /* Is this comparison in any way safe, defined, portable? */
    if (d == DBL_MIN)
        puts("foo failed");

    return 0;
}
```

I know, that usually you shouldn't equal compare double values, as rounding errors and alike could occur, but in this case it's a constant (I think).

Comment: If you return exact value, you compare exact values. You don't compare, say `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3`

Comment: If you want to have an invalid value indicator, use `NAN` (unless you want to support C implementations without NaN support, which is not common). Note that you cannot test whether `x` is a NaN with `x == NAN`; you should use `isnan(x)` after including `<math.h>`.

Comment: Perhaps `DBL_TRUE_MIN` would be better.  (Also look into `HUGE_VAL`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the comparison itself goes, this should be fine.

You're potentially missing out on some optimisations this way, because the range of your results is not just the real values - but that shouldn't be a huge issue.

Suggestion if you can still change the interface: A more readable solution could be something like:

```
double result;
int err = foo_fail(&result);
```

Comment: Actually my current interface uses an opaque handle with an error type indicator.
So, the user can use `if (getLastError(handle) != PREFIX_OK)` to test for an error case. I just wanted to give more options if possible.